# Traceback show only exception type and nothing about Pydantic serializing errors

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I would like to print in traceback triggered fields because without that I can't get what's wrong in code. I have

```
raise ResponseValidationError(
    fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError
```

what I want to get:

```
in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for UserOut
response -> id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> email
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> created_at
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Endpoint function:

```py
@router.get("", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, response_model=List[PostOutTEST])
async def get_posts(
    db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_db),
    current_user=Depends(get_current_user),
    limit: int = None,
    offset: int = None,
    contains: str = "",
    order=None,
):

    posts = await get_join_table(db, Post, Vote)
    return posts
```

Pydantic model:

```py
class PostBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: Optional[bool] = True

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

class PostOutTEST(PostBase):
    Post: PostBase
    votes: int
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set exception handler and print error message inside:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.exception_handlers import (
    http_exception_handler,
    request_validation_exception_handler,
)
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException

app = FastAPI()


@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def custom_http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    print(f"OMG! An HTTP error!: {repr(exc)}")
    return await http_exception_handler(request, exc)


@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
    print(f"OMG! The client sent invalid data!: {exc}")
    return await request_validation_exception_handler(request, exc)
```

Docs: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#re-use-fastapis-exception-handlers

Comment: The problem that fastapi have raise an error but i want to find why that pydantic didnt. If pydantic will be raising an error i can find the message with problematic fields

Comment: Pydantic does raise the error, but fastapi catches all exceptions. You can add your logic as I showed and print these errors